# Can't build very simple tcl application

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to write a *very* simple Tcl application in C++:

```
#include <tcl.h>

#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Calling Tcl_FindExecutable." << std::endl;
    Tcl_FindExecutable (argv[0]);

    std::cout << "Calling Tcl_CreateInterp." << std::endl;
    Tcl_Interp *pInterp = Tcl_CreateInterp ();

    if (Tcl_Eval (pInterp, "puts stdout {Hello, World!}") != TCL_OK)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << Tcl_GetStringResult (pInterp) << std::endl;
        return (0);
    }

    if (Tcl_Eval (pInterp, "puts stdout [info nameofexecutable]") != TCL_OK)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << Tcl_GetStringResult (pInterp) << std::endl;
        return (0);
    }

    return (1);
}
```

I can compile it via `g++ -c Wall -I/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/include noddy.cpp -o noddy.o`

but when I link it, with `g++ -L/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/lib -ltcl8.6 -o noddy noddy.o`

I get errors saying that all the Tcl library procedures are undefined.

What am I doing wrong, please?

**Edit**

The actual commands were

```
$ g++ -c -Wall -I/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/include noddy.cpp -o noddy.o
$ g++ -L/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/lib -ltcl8.6 -o noddy noddy.o
noddy.o: In function 'main':
noddy.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to 'Tcl_FindExecutable'
noddy.cpp:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to 'Tcl_CreateInterp'
noddy.cpp:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to 'Tcl_Eval'
noddy.cpp:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to 'Tcl_GetStringResult'
noddy.cpp:(.text+0xda): undefined reference to 'Tcl_Eval'
noddy.cpp:(.text+0xef): undefined reference to 'Tcl_GetStringResult'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Your code works for me when I build and link it using visual studio. You might want to give some actual command output as your link step doesn't appear to include the object file

Comment: It's a typo @patthoyts, I have corrected it now.

Comment: So what's _actually_ in `/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/lib`?

Comment: Lots of good stuff, including libtcl8.6.a and libtcl8.6.so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In link statements the order of object modules and libraries is significant. You should include the object first and then the libraries (redone as C to avoid installing g++):

```
> gcc -Wall -I/opt/tcl/include -c noddy.c
> gcc -o noddy.exe noddy.o -L/opt/tcl/lib -ltcl86
> noddy
Calling Tcl_FindExecutable.
Calling Tcl_CreateInterp.
Hello, World!
C:/Code/noddy.exe
```

But:

```
> gcc -o noddy.exe -L/opt/tcl/lib -ltcl86 noddy.o
noddy.o:noddy.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to '_imp__Tcl_FindExecutable'
noddy.o:noddy.c:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to '_imp__Tcl_CreateInterp'
noddy.o:noddy.c:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to '_imp__Tcl_Eval'
noddy.o:noddy.c:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to '_imp__Tcl_GetStringResult'
noddy.o:noddy.c:(.text+0x9b): undefined reference to '_imp__Tcl_Eval'
noddy.o:noddy.c:(.text+0xad): undefined reference to '_imp__Tcl_GetStringResult'
e:/opt/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: noddy.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section '.eh_frame'
e:/opt/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Many thanks @patthoyts; I was fairly sure I was overlooking something pretty simple and obvious.